# Android emulator does not refresh its display

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator

I am running Android Studio on Windows 7 and 10 and the Android Studio emulator does not update its display automatically. This is already the case upon starting the AVD ie not related to a program I upload. HAXM is installed.

I can force a re-draw by rotating the emulator. I already tried re-activating Windows' animations etc.

The emulator refreshes the display normally when I deactivate hardware rendering in the AVD settings (but this is slow).

Answer (score 2):

I now found the problem: It is the Windows 10 high-contrast color themes (one of which I selected). For some reason it does not update window contents.

I also did an experiment: wrote an OpenGL program which updates the window contents correctly in the default theme but when using high-contrast themes then only updates on double alt-tab.

So I think that this might affect all Windows 10 users using high-contrast themes that want to run certain OpenGL programs!

Temporary workaround: I tried adding InvalidateRect but it did not help. I added MoveWindow, but resizing to the same width&height does nothing; using MoveWindow to change to a different width&height and back works(!) but is an ugly and visible hack.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a sum problem in emulator.then you can crater a new emulator or restart a Android Studio And try again.or check package of emulator from SDk Manager and install it.